# How much resource usage would pattern recognition/image processing take in Android

Tags: android, mobile, image-processing, pattern-matching, computer-vision

I'm writing an Android app that involves some form of pattern recognition to count the number of similar objects in an image. The app would be designed to work with a specific type of objects and would not involve machine learning.

Is the computation and processing within the device for such a scenario feasible or would it be better to send the image over to a remote server?

If the computation can be handled by the device, would a first generation device running on version 2.2 with 528MHz of CPU and 288MB of RAM be able to return an output within a convenient amount of time?

Comment: There's only one way to find out...you know what that is right? Run it and monitor usage! Answer depends on too many factors. Your algo, the complexity of the image, the device itself.

Comment: Your question is too vague. It is impossible to answer it.

Comment: The device camera is used to take an image such as a small crowd of people. The app would then analyse the image and count the number of people in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on your algorithm. There's no universal pattern recognition/image processing algorithm, even for your somewhat specific case of counting similar objects.